# How do I get view controllers like this? (slide one out of the way but still partially see it)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I thought this was a new split view controller but can't figure out how to get my view controllers to behave like this. I've seen it in the Nike Running app, the GoDaddy app and the AT&T app.

I wouldn't be surprised if I'm missing something obvious as I'm kind of new, but how do I get two View Controllers to work like the attached image.

(I'm using Xcode 6 with Swift)

Link to image of what I mean:

http://cdn.appstorm.net/iphone.appstorm.net/iphone/files/2013/10/nike-home.jpg

When I tap the 3 horiztonal lines on the top left of the view controller with the menu view controller slides in and pushes most of the view controller with the km on it mostly off the screen, except for a small section that a user can still click on to get back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently doing the same things for my app and I am following a very [nice tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift) on Ray Wenderlich tutorial website. This tutorial drives you through the process to create a pop-up side menu in Swift.